# Querying mongo array of embedded documents in aggregation pipeline $eq diff value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have an array of mogoDB embedded documents

```js
const ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
    group: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "ArticleGroup" },
});
// ArticleGroup
const ArticleGroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    desc: { type: String, default: "" },
    state: { type: String, required: true, default: "public" },
    members: [
        {
            desc: String,
            role: String,
            user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
        },
    ],
});
// User
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        email: { type: String, unique: true },
        password: String,
    },
);
```

test data :

```js
  {
    _id: "6131aa5b367318e2df14b988",
    title: "功能更新清单",
    author: ObjectId("607edeb4b1e1bea9acb5af38"),
    group: ObjectId("612d00a43c52975d4ade10d4")
  }
```

I want to add a new field 'can_edit' to the document by comparing 'author._id == group.members. User' in 'aggregate' pipeline.

```js
 Article.aggregate([
{
  $lookup: {
       from: "users",
       localField: "author",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "author",
     },
 },
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "articlegroups",
      localField: "group",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "group"
    }
},
  {
     $addFields: {
          can_edit: {
                        $eq: ["$group.members.user", "$author._id"],
                      },
                }
  }
])
```

However, the 'can_edit' I got was always' false ', and I'm sure that the 'author._id' value in my test data is the same as' group.members.

I want to get the data：

```js
  {
    _id: "6131aa5b367318e2df14b988",
    can_edit: true,
    title: "功能更新清单",
    author: {
      _id: "607edeb4b1e1bea9acb5af38",
      email: "frmachao@126.com",
      
    },
    group: {
      _id: "612d00a43c52975d4ade10d4",
      desc: "开发",
      state: "public",
      name: "开发小组",
      members: [
        {
          _id: "612d00a43c52975d4ade10d5",
          role: "admin",
          user: "607edeb4b1e1bea9acb5af38",
          
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Is there any way I can meet my needs? Does anyone know how to do that? I would grateful to you .

Just now, I try :

```
Article.aggregate([
{
  $lookup: {
       from: "users",
       localField: "author",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "author",
     },
 },
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "articlegroups",
      localField: "group",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "group"
    }
},
  {
    $addFields: {
      can_edit: {
        $in: [
          "$author._id",
          "$group.members.user"
        ],
      },
    },
  }
])
```

However, the 'can_edit' I got was always' false '

Comment: provide sample data of group ,
another thing replace `localField: "group"` to `localField: "group._id"` in $lookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`$in (aggregation)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/),

> Returns a boolean indicating whether a specified value is in an array.

```
$in: [
  "$author._id",
  "$group.members.user"
]
```

**Updated:**

Since Post Owner added the issue:

> $in requires an array as a second argument

which means `$group.members` potentially is null and not an array.

Add condition checking for checking `$group.members` must be an array.

```
{
  case: {
    $ne: [
      {
        "$type": "$group.members"
      },
      "array"
    ]
  },
  then: false
},
```

[`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) - Not equal check

[`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) - Return the BSON type of field

Complete query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      can_edit: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $ne: [
                  {
                    "$type": "$group.members"
                  },
                  "array"
                ]
              },
              then: false
            },
            {
              case: {
                $ne: [
                  {
                    "$type": "$group.members"
                  },
                  "array"
                ]
              },
              then: false
            },
            {
              case: {
                $in: [
                  "$author._id",
                  "$group.members.user"
                ]
              },
              then: true
            }
          ],
          default: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample 1 in Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CkNGfbYU2AY)

---

Alternatively, the query can be shortened with `$switch` not needed as `$in` returns the same boolean result.

[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) - Logical AND of multiple expressions

Complete query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      can_edit: {
        $and: [
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                "$type": "$group.members"
              },
              "array"
            ]
          },
          {
            $in: [
              "$author._id",
              "$group.members.user"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample 2 in Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XHx2UrFQZl4)

Comment: Thank you，but still prompt after execution `"$in requires an array as a second argument`; So I wonder if the problem is in the data model ; 
A minute ago, I changed The current questions description：
" group: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "ArticleGroup" }"，In the beginning，I use `    $lookup: {from: "articlegroups",localField: "group",foreignField: "_id",as: "group"}` , 
Does the questions have anything to do with it?

Comment: Hi, is it possible that `group` or `group.members` is no value?

Comment: Hi, updated the answer for `group.members` must be array checking.